# How to merge G Suite Gmails on separate domains?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Company has a **G Suite account** with all the services, e.g. `user007@a.com` emails. **Company changes name from A to B** and gets another a G Suite account with emails `user007@b.com`. Now it is time to c**) ditch the first G Suite**, but first to **a) merge mailboxes,  b) set up domain aliases** so that mail sent to old domain still lands in new domain inboxes. Merging G Drive would also be nice.

I have checked G suite documentation, which is very complicated on this topic, and the instruction often don't work and there are always hurdles. For example you can't add the old domain as an alias to new inboxes, since it is used under a different account, but I don't really wanty to delete it, unless it is attached and verified under the new account, etc...

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: My question stands as it is, in the title. It is then elaborated on, in the first paragraph, a) and b) specifically. The 2nd paragraph is about my effort so far, should it be of any help, or for clarification.

Comment: The answer to the question on the title is "it's not possible'. The body has enough details to know infer that  a workaround will be acceptable but it's not enough to provide a specific one that's not primarily opinion-based. As you said that the official docs aren't clear enough for you I suggest you to hire a consultant.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no direct method provided by **Google** to merge G Suite accounts. But you can always use the automated tool which will perform a function called **Delta Migration**. Solution for all your problem is Delta Migration property in a tool. It will automatically transfer new emails from the old account to a new account. The best tool you can use is **[G Suite Merge](https://datahelpsoftware.com/g-suite/merger/) Tool**. It has the properties which you need to solve your problem.